# Forcing a Regular Expression to match optional groups

Tags: java, regex, scala, parser-combinators

I want to search for a string "W foo X bar Y baz Z" in a text.
W,X,Y,Z are unimportant separators and I must not search for them.
foo, bar and baz are the words I am interested in. The order is not that important.
I want to know how "good" my required words occur in the text.

I am trying the following

```
(?:\Qfoo\E)?.{0,3}(?:\Qbar\E)?.{0,3}(?:\Qbaz\E)?
```

My reasoning is:

- pack each word in an optional group, so it is not required to occur
  [ (?: is a non-capturing group, \Q...\E is just escaping ]
- separate each word with .{0,3} (any character, occuring 0-3 times)

This Regex is always matching since it only consists of optional groups but **the resulting match is always empty**, even if it could fully match all optional groups.
However, I want to post-process the resulting match so I need it to capture as much as possible.

Can I force the Regex to try matching all groups as far as possible?

Or do you have any idea how to accomplish a search for several words, separated by something and later checking which words occurred to calculate some similarity?

Thank you very much

Comment: Well, you have some problems. First - what is legal input? With all your "required words" being optional, and `.{0,3}` twice, the pattern can match any 6 characters (including `"1bar2"`, but not how you expect - without capturing `(bar)`!). Are all groups really optional? Can you define the separators better? I'd start by trying to create a link between the separator and its previous group, for example: `(?:foo.{0,3})?(?:bar.{0,3})?(?:baz)?` (we can do much better if you can clarify and give more examples)

Comment: Why the `?` quantifier if you want to match the text? And what regex methods do you use for matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have some difficulties to tackle your problem by simply using Regex.

I propose you to have a look at a powerful Scala feature, naming Parser Combinator.

Using it, you'll have to ability to combine the use of regex for matching inner elements, and parsing strategies to find them out.

Here is a clear and neat post where you'll find relevant information about this [Parser Combinator](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators).

What can be done is to see your content as

```
delim = "[a-z]{0,3}".r
value = "foo|bar|baz".r
expr = delim ~ value ~ expr
```

My 2c

Comment: I am aware of parser combinators but was not sure if they match my problem, but will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First guess at this I would try a regular expression like this

```
(foo|bar|baz|anyothercombination)
```

and then use the matches count property

(Will just need to look this up and get back to you if you want a snippet)